# Como criar um web-proxy com cURL + PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Preciso criar uma aplicação que consiga comparar algumas informações contidas em sites externos e preciso fazer isso em `PHP`, porém sou barrado pela diferença de domínios. Em **proxys** em consigo acessar essa página, por isso preciso que isso aconteça também dentro da ferramenta, como consigo fazer isso, já pesquisei e nada tem funcionando pra mim, deem a mim uma luz.

**Atualização**

Encontrei essa class que resolveu minha vida, e deixe aqui pra quem precisar também.

`https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy/blob/master/miniProxy.php`

Comment: Já existem ferramentas para isso, [isso](https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy) e [isso](https://github.com/softius/php-cross-domain-proxy), ambos são código aberto, e em PHP, e seguem o mesmo conceito. Se sabe como age um proxy então não terá nenhum problema. Você diz que "nada tem funcionado", não há como adivinhar o que não funcionou.

Comment: @Inkeliz meu amigo kkkk, você deve ta querendo me engolir ai, mas eu não consegui fazer funcionar e não me pergunte porque, porém graças ao deus de cada linha de comando encontrei algo qeu enfim funcionou, vou publicar.